# ubuntu php7 imagick installation problem

Tags: 14.04

I can't install imagick or gd extension to my ubuntu 14.04. Tried many method no solution.

```
sudo apt-get install imagemagick libmagickwand-dev
```

Here is command output:

```
root@mail:~# sudo apt-get install imagemagick libmagickwand-dev Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree Reading state information... Done imagemagick is already the newest version. Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable distribution that some required packages have not yet been created or been moved out of Incoming. The following information may help to resolve the situation:

    The following packages have unmet dependencies:  libmagickwand-dev : Depends: libmagickcore-dev (= 8:6.7.7.10-6ubuntu3.13) but it is not going to be installed E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: Ubuntu 14.04 is EOL now. Consider upgrading your system.

Comment: I can not complete system upgrade from terminal.

Comment: Okay, in that case, edit your question to include the output of `cat /etc/apt/sources.list` and `sudo apt-get install libmagickcore-dev`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have dependencies issues, try to fix them:

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

From `man apt-get`:

> -f, --fix-broken
>              Fix; attempt to correct a system with broken dependencies in place.
>              This option, when used with install/remove, can omit any packages
>              to permit APT to deduce a likely solution. If packages are
>              specified, these have to completely correct the problem. The option
>              is sometimes necessary when running APT for the first time; APT
>              itself does not allow broken package dependencies to exist on a
>              system. It is possible that a system's dependency structure can be
>              so corrupt as to require manual intervention (which usually means
>              using dpkg --remove to eliminate some of the offending packages).
>              Use of this option together with -m may produce an error in some
>              situations. Configuration Item: APT::Get::Fix-Broken.

Comment: Nothing changed. I tried already.